# Tensorflow startup time?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been working with a GPU version of Tensorflow 0.9.0 on my University's cluster. When I submit the job, it begins running and outputs a message such as:

(stuff that says CUDA found the device...)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:808] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)

However after this, it doesn't begin actually processing anything for a long time. It seems like it just hangs there for a while... For the record, I'm using Imagenet data formatted as in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data, and creating all of my Queues, etc. on a CPU and running all variables/operations on the GPU.

I have tried not explicitly calling for the CPU/GPU splits, and permitting the soft_device_placement to do its thing, but this results in the same hang-ups too.

Edit: Should also mention that even when working with the raw .JPEG files (ie: not using the processing techniques above) this still happens. So, I don't think it's much of an issue with that?

Has anybody else experienced this, and is there anyway around it?

Thank you.

Edit: Code snippet

```
AlexNet = ConvNet(G,'AlexNet',k=k,H=H,W=W,D=D)


with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    (assemble AlexNet)

    train_step,cross_entropy = AlexNet.getTrainStep(LR)
    acc = AlexNet.getAccuracyMetric()
    AlexNet.finalizeBuild()

print('file io stuff...')
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    image_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, H,W,D])
    label_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

    if mode == 'local':
        label_batch = tf.one_hot(label_holder,k)
    elif mode =='sherlock':
        label_batch = tf.one_hot(label_holder,k,1,0)

    image_batch = tf.mul(image_holder,1)


    train_dataset = ImagenetData('train')
    val_dataset = ImagenetData('validation')
    train_images, train_labels = image_processing.inputs(train_dataset)
    val_images, val_labels = image_processing.inputs(val_dataset)

    #tf.initialize_all_variables()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=AlexNet.session,coord=coord)

print('beginning training')


val_accs = []
losses = [] 

for itt in range(nitt):
    print(itt)
    ...Training routine
```

Comment: Could it be that it's actually doing work during this time? For instance, the official cifar example can "hang" for >1 minute as it's preloading the images. You can do `sess.run(tf.Print([1], [1], "hi"))` at the beginning to rule out initialization-based slowness.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but here are a few follow up questions: 1. Does it ever start training, and if so after how long? 2. Are the CPU or GPU idle while it's hanging (e.g. what do `top` and `nvidia-smi` say)? 3. Are you using random shuffling in your input pipeline, with a large value for `min_after_dequeue`?

Comment: I didn't know that you could print this way... So basically, I created my model using the GPU (Interactive session), then made the image_processing call with the CPU. If I do something like this:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    AlexNet.session.run(tf.Print([1], [1], 'coordinator made'))

    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=AlexNet.session,coord=coord)

the session works, and every iteration I can call sess.run(tf.Print([1], [1], str(itt))) fine.

If I don't include the AlexNet.session.run(tf.Print([1], [1], 'coordinator made')) line though, the system craps out.

Comment: I added a snippet of code to the original post. Would you mind explaining why this doesn't work as anticipated? When I add the sess.run(tf.Print(..)) function calls, it seems to not hang-up.

Comment: I noticed something similar for any example I run on the GPU. It doesn't hang forever, only a few minutes. But still, after recognizing the device it still takes some time to start processing the data in which I'm not sure what its doing. I imagine its transferring data to the CPU memory. If that's the case , then that would explain why it takes so long for your imagenet experiment.

Comment: As far as I know, this happens with large graphs as tensorflow prepares execution the execution plan and allocates necessary resources.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia drivers take time to wake up for some machines. Run the following command before running the script.

```
sudo nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode
```

Comment: And on Windows?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html 2

Basically that option is Linux only. “On Windows the kernel mode driver is loaded at Windows startup and kept loaded until Windows shutdown.”

Comment: But I got the issue on windows too.